# Iteration in BS4 failing in web scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup 4 to scrape data from a full race greyhound meeting(UK).Here is an example of an Url.
http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135549
 There are usually between 9 and 14 races at each meeting.The code below iterates through each race(event) on the card and prints the data to screen(PyCharm Python v3).The problem is that BS is not completing the iterations and usually fails around about race(event) 7 or 8 on the card and on some occasions breaks down half way through an event(race) by only getting the data for half the runners.And on some occasions I get the standard message "Process finished with exit code 0"I did think it might have something to do with the Url being temporarily unavailable,but it is unusual that the program always seems to default around about the 7th or 8 race event.I have scoured the source code of the various pages and can see no inconsistency in the that code(admit that I am not too familiar with HTML)Any suggestions appreciated.

```
 from urllib import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 baseURL = 'http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135549'
 html = urlopen(baseURL)
 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

 nameList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class": "resultsBlockHeader"})
 for i in nameList:


     nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "track"})
     for j in nameList1:
         print(j.get_text())

     nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "date"})
     for j in nameList1:
         print(j.get_text())

     nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "datetime"})
     for j in nameList1:
         print(j.get_text())

     nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "grade"})
     for j in nameList1:
        print(j.get_text())

    nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "distance"})
    for j in nameList1:
        print(j.get_text())

    nameList1 = i.findAll("div", {"class": "prizes"})
    for j in nameList1:
        print(j.get_text())

nameList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class": "resultsBlock"})
for i in nameList:

    nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "trap"})
    for j in nameList2:
        print(j.get_text())

    nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "first essential fin"})
    for j in nameList2:
        print(j.get_text())

    nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "essential greyhound"})
    for j in nameList2:
        print(j.get_text())

    nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "sp"})
    for j in nameList2:
        print(j.get_text())

    nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "timeSec"})
    for j in nameList2:
        print(j.get_text())

    nameList2 = i.findAll("li", {"class": "timeDistance"})
    for j in nameList2:
        print(j.get_text())
```